# Java method to find set of letters in a String not specific with sequence of Letters?

Tags: java, regex, string

In Java I am developing scramble game for playing with words.

If player1 sends letters like **"B,A,C,N,R,E"**, then again player1 should not send same set of letters ( sequence does not matter ) eg **"A,B,C,N,R,E", "B,A,N,C,E,R"** etc.

**Is there anyway to find the given set of letters in a string not specific with sequence of Letters?**

Comment: I am using String.contains() method, but it is manual search so it is taking time. I m looking for in-built methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corresponding to player1, you can sort and store the sequence he has sent. Next time he chooses a sequence, sort it and do a check in the map

Answer (score 1):

1) Sort the letters as it was said before. Complexity O(n log n).

2) To implement some kind of array with counters where the ordinal number of the simbol in alphabet will be an index in mask array. And use this mask array to match the words.
Just like that Integer[] maskArray = [0(for A),0(for B),0(for C),etc.] Complexity O(n).